# input checkbox add duplicate data in third cycle on checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I write down a function which is bulk deletion on table. There is a table with checkbox on every rows, if some one select checkboxs then click on delete button its shows a confirmation modal, if it is close them modal then no action occurs.

In my case when I checked the boxes modal shows correct selected data, and if I then unchecked their is no problem, problem occurs when third time checked it populate previous unchecked data in modal. means checked -> unchecked -> checked.

```
            let newTableData = "";
        $('.btn-delete-employees-table-danger').hide();
        let modalValue = null;
        let selectedID = null;
        let selectedRow = ""
        let counter = 0;
        console.log($('.btndelete'));
        $(document).on('click', '.btndelete', function(e) {
            $('.btn-delete-employees-table-danger').show();
            if ($(this).prop("checked") == true  || this.checked) {
                counter = counter + 1;
                var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
                selectedRow = $(`.roww[data-id=${id}]`);
                selectedID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
                $(this).closest('tr').addClass('deleteselectedrow')
                if($(this).closest('tr').addClass('deleteselectedrow')) {
                $('.counter-of-selected-emp-modal').html(`${counter} employees will be deleted`)
                        newTableData += `
                        <div class="card mt-3" id="emp-${selectedID}">
                         <div class="d-flex justify-content-between modal-row">
                            <div>
                                <h4>${selectedRow[0].cells[1].innerText}</h4>
                                <p class="light-small-grey-text">ID</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <h4>${selectedRow[0].cells[2].innerText}</h4>
                                <p class="light-small-grey-text">Emp Name</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <h4>${selectedRow[0].cells[3].innerText}</h4>
                            <p class="light-small-grey-text">Emp DOB</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <h4>${selectedRow[0].cells[4].innerText}</h4>
                            <p class="light-small-grey-text">Emp CNIC</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    `
                    console.log(newTableData);
                }
                $('.data-in-modal').html(newTableData);
            } else {
                counter = counter - 1;
                $('.counter-of-selected-emp-modal').html(`${counter} employees will be deleted`)
                selectedID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
                console.log($(selectedRow[0].cells[0].childNodes[1].checked))
                console.log($("#emp-"+selectedID));
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
                $("#emp-"+selectedID).remove();
                $("#emp-"+selectedID).empty();
                $(this).prop("checked") == false;
                $("#emp-"+selectedID).addClass('d-none')
                console.log($('.data-in-modal'));
                console.log(newTableData);

            }
            
            if(counter == 0 ) {
                $('.btn-delete-employees-table-danger').hide();
                $('.data-in-modal').html("");
                newTableData = '';
            }
        });
        function getandsetdate() {
    var date = new Date().toISOString('yyyy-mm-dd').split('T')[0];
    var element = document.getElementById('date')
    element.value = date
    return date
}          
        
        // show confirmation modal
        $('.shown-modal').on('click', function (e) {
            var policy_date_elem = $('input[name="emp_policy_end"]')
            policy_date_elem.val(getandsetdate())
            policy_date_elem.css('border', '1px #ced4da solid')
            $('#showsDependentModal').modal('show');
        })  
        
        $('#btnDelteYes').click(function () {
            $('.deleteselectedrow').remove();
            console.log($('.deleteselectedrow'))
            console.log($('.deleteselectedrow').prevObject[0]);
            $('.btn-delete-employees-table-danger').hide();
            newTableData = ""
            $('#showsDependentModal').modal('hide');
        });
        $('.no-btn').click(function () {
            $('tr').removeClass('deleteselectedrow')
            $('#showsDependentModal').modal('hide');
            
        })


                <table class="table table-bordered sortable empy-table" id="table">
                    <thead class="">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Select
                            </th>
                            <!-- <th>check</th> -->
                            <th>Emp ID</th>
                            <th>Employee Name</th>
                            <th>DOB</th>
                            <th>CNIC</th>
                            <th class="noExport">Details</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="search-table" class="employees_body">
                        <!-- {% for employee in employees %}
                        <tr id="{{ employee.id }}" data-id="{{ forloop.counter }}" class="roww">
                             <td>
                              <input class="btndelete" type="checkbox" name="employee_id" value="{{ employee.id }}"  />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                               {{employee.id}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{employee.first_name}} {{employee.last_name}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{employee.date_of_birth}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{employee.cnic}}
                            </td>
                            <td class="noExport">
                                <a class="text-dark" href="{% url 'smartbenefits:employee_profile' employee.id %}">
                                    <button class="button-detail"><span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span></button>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %} -->
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal hide fade" id="showsDependentModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="showssDependentModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content modal-secondary">
            <div class="px-4 pt-5 w-100">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
                    <div class="">
                        <h4>Please confirm if you want to delete the below employees?</h4>
                        <p class="counter-of-selected-emp-modal"></p>
                    </div>
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close dependent-close-icons-modal no-btn" id="modal-dismiss" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="data-in-modal ">
                   
                </div>
                <div class="policy-end w-25 mt-3">
                    <!-- <input type="text" name="emp_policy_end" readonly vaule="" /> -->
                    <label class="date-detail" for="emp_policy_end">Policy End Date. <span
                        class="fa fa-info-circle"></span></label>
                <span class="hover-message">Policy End date will be same as the current date. For further queries,
                    contact our ops team</span>
                <input id="date" type="date" name="emp_policy_end" readonly />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="button-secondary active" id="btnDelteYes">Confirm</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? If this is a pure JS / jQuery problem, please share the generated markup and not any templating logic. Also, if this is really a CSS problem, please share more details about that connection - otherwise, please remove the tag

Comment: its a pure jquery

Comment: Then please remove the tags that are irrelevant